# Play 2 Heroku startup with multiple dynos

Tags: heroku, playframework-2.0

I have a Play 2.x app up and running on Heroku with a single web dyno.

On startup, an Akka actor is triggered which itself schedules future jobs (e.g. sending push notifications).

```
object Global extends GlobalSettings {

  override def onStart(app:Application) {
    val actor = Akka.system.actorOf(Props[SomeActor])
    Akka.system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(0 seconds, actor, None)
  }
}
```

This works fine with one web dyno but I am curious to know what happens if I turn up the number of web dynos.
Will onStart be executed twice with two web dynos?

Would be great if **Global** really works globally and **onStart** is only executed once, independently of the number of web dynos. If not, multiple dynos have to somehow agree on one dyno responsible for doing the job.

Did anybody run into a similar issue?

Comment: Searching for a solution. What was yours finally?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you run two web dynos, your global will be executed twice. Global is global to the process. When you scale your web process, you are running two processes. You have a couple options:

- Use a different process (aka a singleton process) to run your global. The nice thing about Play is that you can have multiple `GlobalSettings` implementations. When you start your process, you specify the global you want to use with `-Dapplication.global=YourSecondGlobal`. In your procfile, then, you would have `singleton: target/start -Dhttp.port=${PORT} ${JAVA_OPTS} -Dapplication.global=YourSecondGlobal`. Start your web processes and `singleton` process and make sure `singleton` is scaled to 1.
- Use a distributed semaphor to obtain a lock. Each process will then race to obtain a lock -- the one that wins will proceed and the others will fail. If you're using Postgres (as many people do on Heroku), an [advisory lock](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/explicit-locking.html#ADVISORY-LOCKS) is a good choice.

Comment: Thanks Naaman for the good feedback! Didn't know about the `singleton` in ProcFiles. Will give it a try.

Comment: @Naaman Don't you lose a web dyno with this solution? Since singleton couldn't handle HTTP requests (since only dynos with `web` as names do)

Comment: @Mik378 no, singleton acts as a worker. Perhaps it's confusing that the example includes -Dhttp.port, when maybe it doesn't need to (haven't tested to see if it's necessary or not).

Comment: @Naaman Imagine an initial configuration with two bought **web** dynos. The current Procfile would be: `web: target/start -Dhttp.port=${PORT} ${JAVA_OPTS}`. Now, if I'm appending this line to my Procfile: `singleton: target/start -Dhttp.port=${PORT} ${JAVA_OPTS} -Dapplication.global=YourSecondGlobal` and scaling the process to tie 1 dyno max with `heroku ps:scale singleton=1`, I would end with how many **web** dynos? Still 2 + 1 worker (the singleton)? or one would be replaced by the singleton process that is a **worker**, leading to 1 web and 1 worker?

Comment: You'd have two web processes and one singleton process. You can test it on a separate app and see the processes by typing `heroku ps`.

Answer (score 2):

You can also get dyno name at runtime:

```
String dyno = System.getenv("DYNO");
```

so doing a check like this may also work:

```
if(dyno.equals("web.1")) {

}
```