# Play 2.2.2 / Running a scheduler on only one Heroku's dyno:

Tags: heroku, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.2

I own a Play 2.2.2 application.

Actually deployed on Heroku, I have this configuration:

```
$heroku ps 

=== web (1X): `target/universal/stage/bin/myWebApp -Dconfig.resource=prod.conf  -Dhttp.port=${PORT}`
web.1: up 2014/03/05 03:53:05 (~ 9h ago)
web.2: up 2014/03/05 04:10:03 (~ 9h ago)
```

So I own 2 web dynos, each running an instance of my Play application.

Now I want to start a specific Akka scheduler in the `Global.scala` on only one dyno.
Only one since it will be focus on polling an `EventStore` in database, whose ascending order is very important.

It seems that it is possible to specified a specific instance using a specific `Global.scala` using the command option `-Dapplication.global=Global2.scala`.
This would great, since I could create a `Global2.scala` running the scheduler while letting the `Global.scala` untouched and used by all other dynos.

**How should the ProcFile look like to designate the dyno adding the scheduler?**

Currently I have this:

```
web: target/universal/stage/bin/myWebApp -Dconfig.resource=prod.conf  -Dhttp.port=${PORT}
```

I came across this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15273516/play-2-heroku-startup-with-multiple-dynos) but the procedure given in the answer is not very clear to me..

Should it be:

```
web: target/universal/stage/bin/myWebApp -Dconfig.resource=prod.conf -Dhttp.port=${PORT}
singleton: `target/universal/stage/bin/myWebApp -Dconfig.resource=prod.conf -Dhttp.port=${PORT} -Dapplication.global=Global2.scala`
```

and making:

```
heroku ps:scale singleton=1
```

Drawback would be that I'd lose one of the dyno for handling user HTTP requests.
Indeed, the [documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile#scaling-a-process-type) states:

> The web process type is special as it’s the only process type that
>   will receive HTTP traffic from Heroku’s routers. Other process types
>   can be named arbitrarily.

Could anyone give me a hint?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the dyno name at runtime:

```
String dyno = System.getenv("DYNO");
```

So in your code you can run an Akka scheduler by checking the dyno variable:

```
if(dyno.equals("web.1")) {
       Akka.system().scheduler().scheduleOnce(
                Duration.Zero(),
                new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                    // do something
                    }
                },
                Akka.system().dispatcher()
        );
}
```

Comment: But if "web.1" is down, and that I need a new dyno carrying the process, this hardcoded way would not fit, wouldn't it?